# How to change cursor style to pointer on hovering over points of the chart?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using chart.js v.2. library and I am trying to change the cursor style to 'pointer' when the user is hovering over points of chart. (I am going to use this with bar, pie, line charts). It seems that there should be support for this option in charts.js  v.2. but I can't find an example anywhere.

EDIT: 
I did not mention that I was using chart with react, to be more specific I am using this [react wrapper](https://github.com/gor181/react-chartjs-2).

I am importing e.g. chart Line `import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';`

```
class ChartTimelineChart extends Component {



constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.options = {
       responsive: true,
       maintainAspectRatio: false,
       animation: {
            easing:  'easeOutCirc',
            duration: 1000
      },
      pointStyle : 'circle',
            scales: {
                 xAxes: [{
                     display: true,
                     gridLines: {display: false},
                     scaleLabel: {display: true}
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    gridLines: {display: false},
                    ticks: {beginAtZero:true},
                    scaleLabel: {display: true}
               }]
           },
      tooltips: {
        displayColors: false
      },
      legend: false
    };


   searchChart(elem, props, data) {
    //Something... 
   }

  render(){

    return (
        (this.props.selectedYears.length)
        ? (  <div>
          <Line data={this.props.selectedYearsData}
                redraw={true}
                options={this.options}
                getElementAtEvent={elem => this.searchChart(elem, this.props, this.props.selectedYearsData)} />
        </div>)
        : <Line data={{datasets: [], labels: []}}
                redraw={true}
                options={this.options} />
    )
  }
};
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With Chart.js 2.x I use this approach. Just add this in the options:

```
onHover: (event, chartElement) => {
    event.target.style.cursor = chartElement[0] ? 'pointer' : 'default';
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It did! Works like  a charm.

Comment: FYI - In my case, onHover configuration element was found under the "hover" element:  hover: { onHover: hoverfn }

Comment: Lovely solution! Thx

Comment: In my situation, I didn't need the "events: ['mousemove']" line

Comment: @JasonSpence at the time of writing, it was necessary. I have tested it with the latest version and I can confirm that you are correct. Thanks for your comment, I am going to update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I just did it for a bar chart, but I believe the solution might work for you too.
There's a property called "chart-hover", in which you can set a callback. It is triggered every time you enter and leave the chart bar.

This is how my *canvas* looks like:

```
<canvas id="bar-material" chart-hover="onHover" class="chart-horizontal-bar"  chart-data="chartData" chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series" chart-colors="colors" chart-options="options" chart-click="onClick" height="160">
</canvas>
```

This is how *onHover* looks on my controller:

```
$scope.onHover = function (points, evt) {
    if (points.length === 0) {
      evt.toElement.attributes.style.nodeValue = evt.toElement.attributes.style.nodeValue.replace("cursor: pointer;", "")
      return;
    }
    var res = evt.toElement.attributes.style.nodeValue.match(/cursor: pointer;/);
    if (res == null) {
      evt.toElement.attributes.style.nodeValue += "cursor: pointer;"
    }
};
```

Comment: I have already changed the cursor style on canvas hover with css, but this is not really what I want.  I want the cursor to change style on POINTS ( e.g.  with line chart the point where tooltip appears)... Thanks anyway...

Comment: This is exactly what happens with the code above. I've just tested in a line chart and the cursor turns to pointer on points and back to arrow out of them. Have you tried this out?

Comment: pls check the updated question and let me know if and how I can use your solution in my case. Thanks!

Comment: Hummm... That changes the scenario a bit. Have you tried to put a Hover attribute on your Line element?

Answer (score 0):

In chart.js v2.9.4, to ensure the hover effect was only there when actually hovering over a data point, I did the following within `options`:

```js
hover: {
    mode: "nearest",
    onHover: function (e, el) {
        let points = userPricingChart.getElementAtEvent(e);
        if (points.length > 0) {
            e.target.style.cursor = "pointer";
        } else {
            e.target.style.cursor = "default";
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.