# How to change the cursor to a pointer when I hover over a bar in a ChartJS bar chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, chart.js

Here is my chart creation

```
createChart = function (name, contributions, idArray) {
    globalIdArray = idArray;
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: "bar",
        data: {
            labels: name,
            datasets: [{
                label: "Contributions",
                data: contributions,
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2)'
                ]
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            },
            onClick: handleClick,
            onHover: handleHover
        }
    });
```

This is the HTML, everything is JavaScript and resides inside the canvas element.

```
<canvas chart-hover="onHover" id="myChart" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

I made it so when I click on a bar they act as a "drill in" and take my a page with more details.  To do that I used this code:

```
function handleClick(e) {
            debugger;
            var activeElement = myChart.getElementAtEvent(e);
            var designerId = _idArray[activeElement[0]._index];
            window.location.href = "/Display/search/index?designerId=" + designerId;
        }
```

I'd like to make it so my cursor changes to a pointer to let the user know they can click the bar (as it would normally change with a link).  I saw some examples of this on Stack Overflow but they were from the last year or two, the posts included comments asking for an updated version but no solutions.

Here is another post I saw which I believe is the same thing I am trying to accomplish but it didn't work for me.

[How to change cursor style to pointer on hovering over points of the chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41014278/how-to-change-cursor-style-to-pointer-on-hovering-over-points-of-the-chart)

Does anyone know of how I can implement this, using the most recent live version of ChartJS?

Answer (score 5):

I needed the cursor to change only when over a bar or point on a line chart so came up with this simple solution. Place your function outside the chart declaration.

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    data: {...},
    options: {
     onHover: graphHover
    }
});
function graphHover(e, array) {
    if(array.length > 0) {
        e.target.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    }else {
        e.target.style.cursor = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: Short and sweet  You can pass the arrow function as well there.

Answer (score 1):

there is a cursor property in css that you can set.
for example :

```
span.crosshair {
    cursor: crosshair;
}

span.help {
    cursor: help;
}

span.wait {
    cursor: wait;
}
```

Please refer to [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp) link for more information

Comment: Since the whole chart is inside of a <canvas> element wouldn't this change the cursor no matter where on the graph they have it?  I'm interested in having it change only when they are hovering over a bar.

Comment: Maybe you can set a custom class in the parameters, If not, inspect the element and check if there's a class on the bar, you can then set the cursor in your custom css

Comment: I tried inspecting the bar and it just takes me to the canvas element.  Here is that other post I am referencing: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41014278/how-to-change-cursor-style-to-pointer-on-hovering-over-points-of-the-chart  

Is this regular javascript or is he using angular?  I ask because of the $scope.onHover

Comment: @Rfjt if there is a $scope variable, it is most likely angular js variable. You should check chart.js documentation to check if there is a way to customize band, i'm pretty sure there is.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me.  What do you mean by 'band'?

Comment: @Rfjt the thing in the chart, the rows. i don't know how you says it haha